# ¿ Que falla en mi código para superar la condición else if?

Tags: javascript, if, else

tengo este reto que no puedo superar. Solo me falta una de las condiciones a cumplir de las tres siguientes:
orderMyLogic(4) debería devolver "Menos de 5"
orderMyLogic(6) debería devolver "Menos de 10"
orderMyLogic(11) debería devolver "Mayor o igual a 10"
He probado infinidad de cambios y siempre me falta una de las condiciones.
Con este código, estoy superando:
orderMyLogic(6)debería devolver "Menos de 10"
orderMyLogic(11) debería devolver "Mayor o igual a 10" .
Pero me falla esta : orderMyLogic(4) debería devolver "Menos de 5"
Muestro mi código para que vean que estoy haciendo mal.
Gracias.

```js
function orderMyLogic(val) {
  if (val < 10 ) {
    return "Less than 10";
  } else if (val < 5) {
    return "Less than 5";
  } else {
    return "Greater than or equal to 10";
  }
}

// Change this value to test
orderMyLogic(4);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comento lo siguiente así como esta tú código no funciona por que en la primer condición también cabe el número 4, por eso no pasa a tu segundo else if; para que obtengas el valor deseado debes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
function orderMyLogic(val) {
  if (val < 10 && val > 5) {
    return "Less than 10";
  } else if (val < 5) {
    return "Less than 5";
  } else {
    return "Greater than or equal to 10";
  }
}

// Change this value to test
console.log(orderMyLogic(4))
```

> Como puedes notar para controlar el comportamiento en el if agrego un
>   operador lógico llamado AND que pide lo siguiente el valor debe ser
>   menor a 10 y mayor a 5 de este modo cuando escribes el valor 4 no
>   entra en ese if, sino que se pasa al segundo al else if y de este modo
>   logras controlar el comportamiento que estas esperando

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, es lo que me ayudo a entenderlo un poco. Aun así, me tengo que preparar mejor los "else if", no pensé que dieran tanto juego.